# Compare two tables in different oracle databases with python cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

My goal is to compare multiple tables in multiple databases with one table in another database (let's call it base table).

Every table has an ID and a Version. I want to check if the entries of the base table are all up to date and synchron in all other tables (just by checking if ID and VERSION are present in the other tables, ignoring the other columns). I want to compare them as efficient as possible (not querying all data and hold it in memory) because there are more thann 150k data entries.

This hase to happen within a python scipt and i am using cx_Oracle.

My first attempt was to query the ID and Versions from the base table, using a cursor fetch one row after another. but then i would have to create 150k+ selects in the other tables which would be imperformant. Does anyone know how two compare them efficiently?

Code looks like this:

```
schemas = ["x","y","z"]

baseConn = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN TO DATABASE1)
baseCursor = conn.cursor()
baseCursor.execute("SELECT ID, Version FROM XXX")

res = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]


icc_count = int(res)

for schema in schemas:
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN TO DATABASE2)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT ID, VERSION FROM " + schema)

    # compare data of baseCursor and cursor here...
    
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()


baseCursor.close()
baseConn.close()
```

Comment: Can you use DB Links, so that data doesn't have to be transferred more than necessary to Python?  Is there any way a hash of data values can be calculated and compared?  Don't forget to tune `arraysize`, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html

Comment: No, db links should not be used. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can query the id/version from your tables and store them in a dictionary, then iterate over the other table and see if the id/version from that table is present in the first one. Yes, that would require 150k entries in your dictionary. If that's not acceptable or if the number will tend to grow further over time, then consider some way of grouping the id/version into batches. If the id is a simple sequence starting at 1 you could then perform queries that retrieve the first 10k ids, the next 10k ids and so forth.

Comment: How would you find ids and versions which are in your dictionary and not in one of the other tables? Your check would only check the completeness of the dictionary but i rather want to check the completeness of the other tables without storing them all in dictionaries

Comment: I assumed you were simply comparing each of the children to the master. If you have to do a multi-way compare, then you'll have to have all of the keys in memory. In that case, splitting the keys into groups to limit memory use makes sense.